# Customer data not get in helper of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, api, customer-session, react

We have sites in which React as Frontend and Magento 2.4 as Backend in which we are facing an issue to get customer data in helper file when a customer login into frontside React(API).

Do we need to check customer is login? If yes required its group.

I have tried `httpContext(\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext)` and customer session to get and check customer data but it will not give any data.

```
// phpcs:ignoreFile
namespace Vendor\PrintTool\Helper;

use Vendor\ShopifyOrder\Helper\Product as ProductHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
use Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Class Data
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD)
 * phpcs:ignoreFile
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    private $_requestData = [];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    protected $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directoryList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $priceHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $jsonHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
     */
    protected $productResourceModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager
     */
    protected $filterManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository
     */
    protected $assetRepo;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupRegistryFactory
     */
    private $groupRegistryFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderItemRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page
     */
    protected $page;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $layout;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $escaper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
     */
    protected $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder
     */
    protected $filterGroupBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder
     */
    protected $sortOrderBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory
     */
    protected $dataObjectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface
     */
    protected $encryptor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
     */
    protected $coreSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
     */
    protected $cookieManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $resource;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $catalogImageHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     */
    protected $state;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $storeRepository;

    /**
     * Store id
     *
     * @var int|null
     */
    protected $storeId;

    /**
     * Store code
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $storeCode;

    /**
     * @var InvoiceRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $invoiceRepository;

    /**
     * @var ProductHelper
     */
    protected $productHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $backendUrl;

    /**
     * @var apronHelper
     */
    protected $apronHelper;


    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterFace
     * @param Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
     * @param Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper
     * @param Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
     * @param Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResourceModel
     * @param Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager
     * @param Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo
     * @param Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param Magento\Customer\Model\GroupRegistryFactory $groupRegistryFactory
     * @param Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
     * @param Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository
     * @param Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page
     * @param Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
     * @param Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
     * @param Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder
     * @param Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder
     * @param Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory
     * @param Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor
     * @param Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
     * @param Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
     * @param Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $catalogImageHelper
     * @param Magento\Framework\App\State $state
     * @param Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
     * @param InvoiceRepositoryInterface $invoiceRepository
     * @param ProductHelper $productHelper
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterFace,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResourceModel,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupRegistryFactory $groupRegistryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $catalogImageHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository,
        InvoiceRepositoryInterface $invoiceRepository,
        ProductHelper $productHelper,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManagerInterFace;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->priceHelper = $priceHelper;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->productResourceModel = $productResourceModel;
        $this->filterManager = $filterManager;
        $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->groupRegistryFactory = $groupRegistryFactory;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->orderItemRepository = $orderItemRepository;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;
        $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->dataObjectFactory = $dataObjectFactory;
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->coreSession = $coreSession;
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->catalogImageHelper = $catalogImageHelper;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->storeRepository = $storeRepository;
        $this->invoiceRepository = $invoiceRepository;
        $this->productHelper = $productHelper;
        $this->backendUrl = $backendUrl;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

.
.
.
.

    public function getCustomerIsLoggedIn()
    {
        return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }

.
.
.
.

    public function getProductPrice($productType, $width = 8, $height = 8, $panel = 1, $withoutCurrency = false, $sizeunit = 'inch', $cachePrice = null, $storeCode = 'default')
    {
        
.
.
.

$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
$logger->info('getCustomerIsLoggedIn: '.$this->getCustomerIsLoggedIn());

.
.
.
    }

}
```

*Due to large file content I have posted its part.*

Comment: please share the code which you try in helper.

Comment: Hello @DhirenVasoya code is added.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question but do not understand. Are you just trying to get the logged in customer group via the API or is there some other information you need?

Comment: @Craig yes i just required a logged-in customer group if a user is logged in with API.